# Ubuntu: packages Rollback

Tags: 14.04

i have been asked to implement a package management for Ubuntu, which is running fine, my problem is after a lot of researches i cant find the way to perform an automatic package rollback when dependencies exits on that packages. can someone provide me a direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the rolled back version using apt-get it should revert the dependencies as well. If not, you can use aptitude instead of apt-get and alternate options should be provided.

Be careful using aptitude. You may end up with a broken system if you do not pay attention.